# Why is my cheese sauce sweet?

Tags: sauce, cheese

I have made cheese sauce before and it has never been sweet. No problem with butter and flour and then I added milk like before. White sauce was fine. So I added cheese. Yes it was a package of shredded sharp cheddar cheese from Harris Teeters. I know fresh is better but it was what I had. The sauce itself was fine, smooth and creamy, but it was sweet. I used skim milk and I have used packed cheese before but it has been a while. Is it the cheese? Have they added something or is it the skim milk?

Comment: Is it possible you added sugar instead of salt by mistake? It's easily done.

Comment: @GdD - I once returned some pancakes at a local restaurant because they were too salty. The response was "they must have used salt instead of sugar in the batter again". I especially liked the "again".

Comment: My response would be "check please!!"

Comment: Milk is sweet to the taste, lactose IS a sugar. If you've let the milk evaporate a bit more than usual and put less salt than what your taste is accustomed to, and/or if the cheese you've used is also less salted than usual, the natural sweetness of the milk (and cheese) would come forward. Industrial breakfast cereal contains a ton of salt (often more than in crisps) to hide the sweetness.

Answer (score -2):

Carbs in some foods (mostly those that contain simple sugars and highly refined grains, such as white flour and white rice) are easily broken down once broken down they are literally a sugar.

Cooking at too high a temp, or for too long, causes the carbs in the white flour to break down. I think that may be why your sauce is tasting sweet.

Comment: Could you add some references that indicate that complex sugars are broken down into simple sugars by cooking? I can't find any